# Downloading El Capitan from public library with 100 MB limit

Tags: macos

I don't have access to the Internet where I live and I must go to the public library to use it. Unfortunately, there is a 100 MB download limit and I must pause the download and reconnect each time. If I'm a few seconds too late, the El Capitan download automatically goes into the install program and I have to start the download all over again. I once got to 3 GB and lost it all.
Is there any way I can recover the downloaded file when I connect to the Internet each time? I know it is there somewhere but the download process assumes that it has finished somehow and begins the install.

Comment: Is there an Apple Store near where you live?

Comment: follow this guide it provides a direct link, that you can pause unpause with Safari download manager for example, for el capitan pkg https://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/el-capitan-direct-download.html